# Java Spring Web MVC application: Failed to create controller

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I hope someone can help me, I am starting to work with Spring MVC.

I have a java spring MVC web application with this packages: `com.app.controller`, `com.app.modelo`, `com.app.servicio`, y `com.app.repositorio`. In the `repositorio` package I have the `UsuarioRepositorio` interface, in the `servicio` package I have the `UsuarioServicio` class. The controller uses the `UsuarioServicio` class and this one uses de `UsuarioRepositorio` interface. The controller initializes the `UsuarioServicio` object in it´s constructor. When running the project it shows this error:

> The module has not been deployed.
> See the server log for details.
>
> [Payara 5.2021.10] [GRAVE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=90 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1643303084394] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.app.controller.UsuarioController.()]]

### `UsuarioRepositorio` interface

```java
package com.app.repositorio;

import com.app.modelo.UsuarioModelo;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsuarioRepositorio extends JpaRepository<UsuarioModelo, Integer>{
    
    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsuario(String CodigoUsuario);
    
    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsarioEstatus(String CodigoUsuario, boolean EstatusLogeado);

    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsuarioIntentos(String CodigoUsuario, int CantidadIntentos);
}
```

### `UsuarioServicio` class

```java
package com.app.servicio;

import com.app.modelo.UsuarioModelo;
import com.app.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UsuarioServicio {
    private final UsuarioRepositorio repouser;
    
    public UsuarioServicio(UsuarioRepositorio ru){
        repouser = ru;
    }
    
    public UsuarioModelo registrarUsuario (String usuario){
        if (usuario == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            UsuarioModelo usermodel = new UsuarioModelo();
            usermodel.setCodigoUsuario(usuario);
            return repouser.save(usermodel);
        }
    }
    
    public UsuarioModelo autentica(String usuario){
        return repouser.porUsuario(usuario).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

### `Controller`

```java
package com.app.controller;

import com.app.modelo.UsuarioModelo;
import com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio;
import com.app.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    private UsuarioServicio userserv;
        
    public UsuarioController(UsuarioServicio us){
        userserv = us;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String getLoginPage(Model modelo) {
        modelo.addAttribute("loginrequest", new UsuarioModelo());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/index")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute UsuarioModelo usermod){
        UsuarioModelo logeduser = userserv.autentica(usermod.getCodigoUsuario());
        logeduser = logeduser == null ? userserv.registrarUsuario(usermod.getCodigoUsuario()) : logeduser;
        return logeduser == null  ? "error_page" : "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

I think the error could be due to a misconfiguration of the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file because I remove the `UsuarioServicio` from the controller and the application runs perfectly

### `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">UsuarioController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    
    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />-->
    
    <bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController"/>

</beans>
```

### `web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### `applicationContext.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

### `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXX;databaseName=XXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialeg = org.hibernate.dialect.sqlserver
```

I modified the dispatcher-servlet like this:

```xml
<bean name="UsuarioController" 
    class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
        <constructor-arg type="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" 
        value="us"/>
</bean>
```

Now the error is this:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'UsuarioController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

I have updated the dispatcher-servlet.xml file like this

```
    <bean name="UsuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" id="us"/>
<bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
    <constructor-arg type="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" ref="UsuarioServicio" />
</bean>
```

and like this

```
   <bean name="UsuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" id="us"/>
<bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
    <constructor-arg ref="UsuarioServicio" />
</bean>
```

Both cases the error is noew this

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio.()]]

I modified the dispatcher-servlet like this:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repositorio"/>
    <bean name="UsuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" id="us">
        <constructor-arg ref="UsuarioRepositorio"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
        <constructor-arg type="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" ref="UsuarioServicio" />
    </bean>
```

And I got this error

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 59; El prefijo "jpa" para el elemento "jpa:repositories" no está enlazado.]]

Then I removed de prefix "jap" like this

```
<repositories base-package="com.app.repositorio"/>
<bean name="UsuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" id="us">
    <constructor-arg ref="UsuarioRepositorio"/>
</bean>
<bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
    <constructor-arg type="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" ref="UsuarioServicio" />
</bean>
```

and the error is this

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 55; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido a partir del elemento 'repositories'. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}'.]]

I did some research and found some configurations to do in the dispatcher-servlet

dispatcher-servle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-2.6.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-5.3.xsd" >

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="UsuarioServicio"/>
    
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">UsuarioController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
The index controller.

<bean name="indexController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="index" />-->
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.repositorio" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repositorio"/>
     
    <bean id="UsuarioRepositorio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio" >
       
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="UsuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio">
        <constructor-arg name="ur" ref="UsuarioRepositorio"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="UsuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
        <constructor-arg ref="UsuarioServicio"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

now the error seems to be with this line <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.repositorio" />

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 46; columnNumber: 54; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: El comodín coincidente es estricto, pero no se ha encontrado ninguna declaración para el elemento 'context:component-scan'.

I added this line @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.repositorio" }) to the UsuarioRepositorio interface, now the file is this

UsuarioRepositorio interface

```
package com.app.repositorio;

import com.app.modelo.UsuarioModelo;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.repositorio" })
public interface UsuarioRepositorio extends JpaRepository<UsuarioModelo, Integer>{
    
    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsuario(String CodigoUsuario);
    
    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsarioEstatus(String CodigoUsuario, boolean EstatusLogeado);

    Optional<UsuarioModelo> porUsuarioIntentos(String CodigoUsuario, int CantidadIntentos);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the content of the `applicationContext.xml` file?

Comment: Additionally, could you please provide the Spring Data JPA configuration to provide the implementation of the `UsuarioRepositorio` interface?

Comment: Thanks, I add the applicationContext.xml file, I  just realized that the project does not have the Spring Data JPA configuration

Comment: Thank you for the update! To resolve the current error, please, consider updating the XML configuration: add the `UsuarioServicio` bean, use the **reference** to the `UsuarioServicio` bean for the `UsuarioController` bean (for example: `<constructor-arg ref="yetAnotherBean" />`; please, note: `ref`).

Comment: Thanks you for the help! I did what you suggested, there are the results, I still can't see the cause

Comment: Again, thank you for the update! Moving forward. Please, activate the Spring Data JPA repository bean support: `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repositorio"/>`. Then, please, define the `UsuarioServicio` bean with the `UsuarioRepositorio` bean as `<constructor-arg ref="usuarioRepositorio" />` (please, note the case: `usuarioRepositorio`).

Comment: Once again thanks for the help. I tried the suggestion, there are the results. I think the error is no only in the dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Again, thank you for the update! I think the question has become complex. Let's finish with the question. I am going to provide the summarising answer. Please, consider asking multiple simple questions instead of one complex question next time.

Comment: I have just posted the summarising answer. Could you please check it thoroughly?

Comment: hello friend, I made that configuration and solved some errors, now the error is with context:component-scan element, I will post the details

Answer (score 0):

## Corrections

The below corrections are ordered from lower level layers to higher level ones.

### Correction #1: Persistence layer: Activate the Spring Data JPA repository bean support

Add the `jpa` XML namespace:

```
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
```

Update the `xsi:schemaLocation` XML schema location by adding the following:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
```

Then add the `repositories` element:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repositorio" />
```

As a result:

> Each bean is registered under a bean name that is derived from the interface name, so an interface of `UserRepository` would be registered under `userRepository`.
>
> — [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring).

Therefore, this should provide the `usuarioRepositorio` bean for our case.

For more details and a complete example, please, see the page: [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#jpa.namespace).

### Correction #2: Application service layer: Add `UsuarioServicio` bean

Use the **reference** to the `usuarioRepositorio` bean for the `usuarioServicio` bean.

```xml
<bean id="usuarioServicio" class="com.app.servicio.UsuarioServicio">
    <constructor-arg ref="usuarioRepositorio" />
</bean>
```

Please, note the case used for the `id` and `ref` attribute values: `usuarioServicio`, `usuarioRepositorio`.

### Correction #3: Integration layer: Update `UsuarioController` bean

Use the **reference** to the `usuarioServicio` bean for the `usuarioController` bean.

```xml
<bean id="usuarioController" class="com.app.controller.UsuarioController">
    <constructor-arg ref="usuarioServicio" />`
</bean>
```

Please, note the case used for the `id` and `ref` attribute values: `usuarioController`, `usuarioServicio`.